# PostGIS role limitations overcome via QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, editing, permission

I'm using PostgreSQL 14 with PostGIS extension. I've created the following role and grants

```
create role prueba login nocreatedb password 'prueba';

grant select, references, trigger 
on all tables in schema public 
to prueba;
```

However, when I access the schema using this role *via* QGIS (3.22), I can edit a layer and save it. What would be the code to avoid that role editing the tables/layers of the schema?

Comment: You haven't actually secured the data, so QGIS isn't actually *overcoming* anything. This is more a database security model issue, which might be better researched in [dba.se]. If you want to restrict access, then you might be better off using a schema other than `public`.

Comment: Would be better to add as an answer

Comment: there is more to it than than please research https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/creating-a-read-only-postgres-user